# Visualize the optimal point for distribution with three parameters

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I want to visualize to any distribution with two or three parameter

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[λ Exp[λ (1 - x)], {x, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> λ > 0]
data = {1.4, 5.1, 1.7, 1.6, 1.1, 3.9, 2.2, 1.3, 2., 1.5};

param = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist]

Plot[
 LogLikelihood[dist, data], {λ, .1, 2},
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, 
            Point[{λ, LogLikelihood[dist, data]} /. param]}
]
```

[image: image for illustration]

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I want to draw the image for three parameters(image for each parameters) but I don't know how i write it?

Comment: if anyone can draw for any distribution with two or three parameters to i do like him I will be thank for him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = (SeedRandom[1234]; RandomVariate[
   NormalDistribution[2, 1/2], 20])

(* {1.74583, 1.9647, 1.20305, 2.7683, 3.33901, 1.34158, 1.45272, 2.07147, \
2.05208, 1.16345, 2.01788, 2.08509, 2.46734, 1.58657, 1.95452, 2.5167, \
1.81824, 2.0943, 1.93193, 1.95803} *)

dist = NormalDistribution[m, s];

param = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist]

(* {m -> 1.97664, s -> 0.511284} *)

llf = LogLikelihood[dist, data] // Simplify

(* (-41.6851 + 39.5328 m - 10. m^2 - 18.3788 s^2 - 20. s^2 Log[s])/s^2 *)
```

Or manually calculating the `llf`

```
llf === (Total@Log[PDF[dist, #] & /@ data] // PowerExpand // Simplify)

(* True *)

Show[
 Plot3D[llf,
  {m, 1, 3}, {s, 1/4, 3/4},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16, Bold] & /@
     {"m", "s", "llf"}),
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7],
  ClippingStyle -> None],
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{m, s, llf} /. param]}]]
```

[image]

For a three-parameter distribution you need three plots, one each with one of the parameters fixed and plot the `llf` with the other two.

Comment: how i ask about one each with one of the parameters fixed please?

Comment: Set one of the parameters to its value in `param` and plot the `llf` as a two-parameter function of the other two parameters. Repeat for each parameter.

Comment: couldn't draw 2d instead of 3d?

Comment: To draw 2D you would need to fix two parameters and plot against the third. Again using multiple plots.

Comment: Thanks you very much